# Unable to figure out where to add wait statement in python selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am searching elements in my list(one by one) by inputing into searchbar of a website and get apple products name that appeared in search result and printed. However I am getting following exception

```
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

I know its because of changing of element very fast so I need to add wait like

```
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "submitbutton")))
```

or explictly

Q1. But I don't understand where should I add it? Here is my code. Please help!

Q2. I want to go to all the next pages using but that's not working.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath( '//div[@class="no-hover"]/a' ).click()
```

Earlier exception was raised on submitton button and now at if statement.

Comment: Which line does raise the exception?

Comment: @amirouche: Earlier exception was raised on 3rd line now on 9th. Updated for your convinience.Thanks!

Comment: What does this line `for element in list in mylist` suppose to do? How your `list`/`mylist` looks like?

Comment: @Andersson: mylist=[mobile, laptop, ipad....] these elements are sent to the search bar on the website. And search is performed. After that all apple product names are listed!

Comment: What site are you using?

Comment: Great... can you give us some sample search terms that might or might not contain 'apple'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not what implicit wait is for. Since the page change regularly you can't be sure when the current object inside the variable is still valid.

My suggestion is to run the above code in loop using try except. Something like the following:

```
for element in mylist:
    ok = False
    while True:
        try:
           do_something_useful_while_the_page_can_change(element)
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
           # retry
           continue
        else:
           # go to next element
           break
```

Where:

```
def do_something_useful_while_the_page_can_change(element):
    searchElement = driver.find_element_by_id("searchbar")
    searchElement.send_keys(element)
    driver.find_element_by_id("searchbutton").click()
    items_count = 0
    items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name( 'searchresult' )
    for i, item in enumerate( items ):
        if 'apple' in item.text:
            print ('item.text')
    items_count += len( items )
```

Comment: I am sorry! That I tried but I am unable to understand what to put where. I mean can you please help me in putting the content inside these tags?Will understand!Thanks!

Comment: You must create a function that supposed to do the whole process for a given tag where there is a comment saying `try to do the action`.

Comment: Still not following it!

Comment: Have a look again

Comment: That didnt work. Only first element is getting printed in loop

Answer (score 0):

I think what you had was doing too much and can be simplified. You basically need to loop through a list of search terms, `myList`. Inside that loop you send the search term to the searchbox and click search. Still inside that loop you want to grab all the elements off the page that consist of search results, `class='search-result-product-url'` but also the text of the element contains 'apple'. The XPath locator I provided should do both so that the collection that is returned all are ones you want to print... so print each. End loop... back to next search term.

```
for element in mylist:
    driver.find_element_by_id("search-input").send_keys(element)
    driver.find_element_by_id("button-search").click()
    # may need a wait here?
    for item in driver.find_elements_by_xpath( "//a[@class='search-result-product-url'][contains(., 'apple')]" ):
        print item.text
```

Comment: The IDs on the site are a little different than what you specified in your code. I'm looking at the US site so it may be different than the site you are looking at so you may need to adjust things.

Comment: Hi,Thanks a lot for your reply .I am getting StaleElementReferenceException: as I have mentioed in question. So adding wait is my concern! Can you syntactically tell me how do I add wait here?Thanks!

Comment: I have many other things and I need 'i' for some other operation so I cannot remove that parameter from my code. So, as per my little brain, I guess code has to be the same.The exception is rising at if statement

Comment: There shouldn't be a StaleElementException from this code... there's nothing to go stale that shouldn't be taken care of. As for the wait, I put a comment in where the wait might go but that's another question that's already been answered many other places that you can google.

Comment: Actually, one keyword is being searched and before completing the process another keyword is getting entered so I am getting StaleElementException

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149611/discussion-between-programmer-and-jeffc).